# Sorting out my Site.Master

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, reference, hyperlink, master-pages

So I am talking about links in a Asp.net mvc2 application, where you have a site master.

In particular, my Site.Master references jQuery, like so:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

But lo an behold, as I have just noticed, this obv isn't going to work e.g.

http://localhost:xxxx/

http://localhost:xxxx/this/no/longer/refs/correct/spot

How can I reference the correct folder regardless how nested the page is?

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922997/asp-net-mvc-resolve-urls-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use url helpers when dealing with urls:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")"></script>
```