# how to create javascript relative action links in mvc projects

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in mvc project. I am using javascript modules in js files to perform some operations.

I am creating and using links in js files. For example accessing an image file.

```
var selectIcon = function() {
       return "/Images/ui/ShapefileLine16.png";
}
```

and I want to send request to an action method in Product controller like this.

```
this.getProducts = function () {
     $.get('Product/GetProjducts', {  }, this.products);
}
```

This codes are working on development time, visual studio IIS express.

But when I publish the project on IIS virtual directory under Default Web Site, the functions are not working. image and controller action resources can not found.

How can I access resources relatively? (@Url.ActionLink is working in MVC but I can not use it)

Comment: It has been discussed many times on SO [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640559/asp-net-mvc-url-action-in-external-js-file), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922997/asp-net-mvc-resolve-urls-in-javascript), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012610/generating-an-action-url-in-javascript-for-asp-net-mvc)... Just a simple search by keywords would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's never really a good idea to hardcode URLs, you should use [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for static resources and [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for controller actions

```
var selectIcon = function() {
    return '@Url.Content("~/Images/ui/ShapefileLine16.png")';
}

this.getProducts = function() {
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Products")', {}, this.products);
}
```

Comment: I can use @Url helper in <script> code, but gives error in js files.

Comment: @bookmarker if you are using this code in a separate JS file then you would need to pass the URLs as parameters from the view.